# Internationalization of string.xml issue

Tags: android, resources, localization, internationalization, locale

In my application I do have several different string resources each per locale like:

```
res/values/string.xml //default
res/values-en/string.xml //english
res/values-it/string.xml //italian
```

Now the problem - each of files contains hundreds of keys and from time to time I can't really define which language is lacking some keys. Say:

```
<string name="yes">Yes</string> <!-- Default -->
<string name="yes">Yes</string> <!-- English -->
<string name="yes">Si</string> <!-- Italian -->
```

And if in German string.xml there'll be no "yes" key corresponding value will be default "Yes" instead of German "Ja" - which is disaster.

Help me to find a way to define lacking string resource keys.

Comment: what tool did you find in IntelliJ to do the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try [MOTODEV Studio](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/). You can use it a standalone IDE (based on Eclipse) or as an Eclipse Plugin. What you would like is an editor, which includes, that makes really easy working with localizable strings. It will show you in a same view all the files as columns, so you will not need to do any merge or diff whatsoever.

Comment: Thanx a lot. Your post forced me to look inside my IDE (Intellij IDEA) and I found nice tool inside.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://winmerge.org/

You can compare files easily.

Comment: Yeahh - I installed it and find very usefull, though it's lacking key by key comparison, just line by line comparison

Answer (score 0):

copy all the files to one text file,, Sort the file and then check one key at once,, loooong method but the most effective one

Comment: Also Sorting all the files and then comparing them